# Jquery slimscroll scrollto on anchor link click

Tags: jquery, slimscroll

So, I've got a div that has a series of sections in it that is controlled overflow by the slimscroll plug in. It works great, except I have a series of anchor links outside the div that I want to have scrollto the specified section on click with slimscroll.

I know it can be done, I'm just drawing a complete blank right now.

Basically, the set up is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
  <section id="1"></section>
  <section id="2"></section>
  <section id="3"></section>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <a href="#1">link</a>
  <a href="#2">link</a>
  <a href="#3">link</a>
</div>
```

I need those links to scroll to the specified anchor within the container div that uses slimscroll.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.